# "So" and "yet" as conjunctive adverbs rather than coordinators

Tags: punctuation, adverbs, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

I have recently been digging into the "FANBOYS" concept and how "so," "yet," and "for" are not truly coordinating conjunctions in the same vein as the other four. Moreover, I have read that "so" and "yet" function similarly to conjunctive adverbs. If that's the case, is it acceptable to treat them like other adverbs and place them after a period/semicolon with a comma afterward? Or should they still only receive the typical FANBOYS treatment? For example:

> He didn't want to come into work, so he said he was sick. (as a coordinator)

> He didn't want to come into work, and so he said he was sick. (as an adverb alongside a coordinator)

> He didn't want to come into work; so, he said he was sick. (as a conjunctive adverb)

I know the first is accepted as correct, but is either of the other two acceptable in a formal setting?

Comment: IMO the third example using a semicolon should be "He didn't want to come into work; he said he was sick."

Comment: Trouble is that *so* and *yet* mean many things, call them polysemous. So in other lives, they can yet be adjectivial.

Comment: Why would you want to insert all that extra punctuation? 3 is unnecessary but not definitely wrong (some authorities might object but I'm sure you'd find similar examples in classic literature; although certainly some classic novelists had strange punctuation).

Answer (score 1):

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/so) licenses the resultative meaning ['and therefore'] of **and so** (though not the use of **so** itself as a coordinator in formal registers):

> In formal English, *so* is not used as a conjunction, to indicate either
> purpose (he left by a back door so he could avoid photographers) or
> result (the project was abandoned so his services were no longer
> needed). In the former case *to* or *in order to* should be used instead,
> and in the latter case *and so* or *and therefore* would be more
> acceptable.
>        [Hence     •*The project was abandoned and so his services were no longer needed*].

.........

It also licenses the independent–clause-initial use of **so** (for sentences; this must allow for the use after semicolons):

> Like *and*, *but*, and *or*, *so* can occur as a transitional word at
> the beginning of a sentence:
>
> - *So all our hard work finally brought results.*

Stylewise, though, I'd personally avoid the semicolon usage as rather ugly. A comma, or a dash/ellipsis to signal a longer dramatic pause, in informal registers, or 'and so' in formal ones.